# What do these Swift error messages mean? (Function declares an opaque return type...)

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a simple Swift struct (this happens to be SwiftUI)

This is the original...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

If I add one simple assignment statement, like this, I get a bunch of errors:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let x = 1
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Why do I get these error messages?  What do they mean?  (I understand #2, but I don't get #1 & #3)
Why do I get these messages after adding a simple assignment statement?

1. Function declares an opaque type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type.
2. Initialization of an immutable value 'x' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.
3. Result of 'Text' initializer is unused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first piece of code, you're taking advantage of [Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID99). That means, if a closure consists of only a single line, compiler implicitly returns the value of that line. If your closure is longer however, you need to explicitly write `return`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let x = 1
        return Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Other two are just warnings and they mean the same thing: you declare something, but never use it. You never use `x`, and since you no longer take advantage of implicit return from closure, you never use `Text` either.

Answer (score 1):

One of the new features of Swift 5 is that we can omit the word `return` if the method/computed property only consists of one single return statement. So this:

```
func f() -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
func f() -> Int {
    1
}
```

So if we expand the first code snippet, it becomes:

```
var body: some View {
    // the word "return" is implicitly added
    return Text("Hello, World!")
}
```

This is a computed property called `body`.

When you add one more line, the computed property no longer consists solely of one single return statement, so now the word `return` can't be omitted. The compiler tries to find a return statement, but can't, hence error #1.

Since the compiler doesn't know that you are actually tying to *return* `Text(...)`, it's confused as to why you are calling an initialiser and doing nothing with it, hence error #3.